# Pandas, create missing dates dictionary from dates column

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a DataFrame which contains data from last year, but the dates column has some missing dates

```py
         date
0      2019-10-21
1      2019-10-29
2      2019-11-01
3      2019-11-04
4      2019-11-05
```

I want to create a dictionary of gaps between dates, so keys would be start dates and values as end dates, something like:

```py
dates_gaps = {2019-10-21:2019-10-29, 2019-10-29:2019-11-01,2019-11-01:2019-11-04 ...}
```

so I created a column to indicate whether a gap exists with the following:

```py
df['missing_dates'] = df[DATE].diff().dt.days > 1
```

which outputs the following:

```
# True indicates if there's a gap or not
0    2019-10-21          False
1    2019-10-29           True
2    2019-11-01           True
3    2019-11-04           True
4    2019-11-05          False
```

and I'm having trouble going forward from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add condition for compare missing values, convert `date` columnto strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and last create dictionary with `zip`:

```
diff = df['date'].diff()
s = df.loc[(diff.dt.days > 1) | diff.isna(), 'date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (s)
0    2019-10-21
1    2019-10-29
2    2019-11-01
3    2019-11-04
Name: date, dtype: object

d = dict(zip(s, s.shift(-1)[:-1]))
print (d)
{'2019-10-21': '2019-10-29', '2019-10-29': '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01': '2019-11-04'}
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert these dates into `datetime` and find the difference between two adjacent dates.

```py
a = pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
b = pd.to_datetime('1900-02-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
c = a-b
c.days  # -31
```